# problems with the transfer of patient records for data at the table archives

Tags: java, sql-server

please I have a little problem with the transfer of patient records for data at the table
  the code using it  :

```
 try {
        //Statement mystt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        int row= affichagetable_pt.getSelectedRow();
        String Table_click=( affichagetable_pt.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
        String query="insert into archives_pt (numfiche_pt,datefiche_pt,nom_pt,prenom_pt,datenaissance_pt,gsm_pt,cin_pt,profession_pt,sexe_pt,adresse_pt,nomsons_pt,cinsons_pt) select numfiche_pt,datefiche_pt,nom_pt,prenom_pt,datenaissance_pt,gsm_pt,cin_pt,profession_pt,sexe_pt,adresse_pt,nomsons_pt,cinsons_pt from patient where  patient.numfiche_pt='"+Table_click+"'";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Effacement OK");
        pst.close();
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        // TODO: handle exception
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e2);

    }
```

the error :

[image]

e2 message is "the statement did not return the result set"

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Can you translate the error message to english?

Comment: Please post full stack trace of your e2 instead of just message. use e2.printStackTrace(); and copy console logs here.

Comment: the statement did not return the result set

Comment: e2  = "the statement did not return the result set"

Answer (score 0):

Use `execute` statement for data manipulation like insert, update and delete and  `executeQuery` for data retrieval like select.
replace

`pst.executeQuery`

with

`pst.execute();`

Comment: without result bro :/

Comment: please update your question and write complete stack trace of exception

Answer (score 0):

End your INSERT statement with a semi-colon before starting your SELECT statement:

```
...,cinsons_pt); select...
```

Comment: I think this is not true, he wants to insert values from select statement.

Comment: Oh, you may be right.   If that's the case, then Mojtaba's solution is close.   He would need to use ExecuteNonQuery() and not try to populate a resultset at all.   (remove the `rs=` completely)